# How can I display all the entities in a legend?

Tags: r, bar-chart, legend

I have this stacked bar chart which has years and countries but I am facing a problem with the legend since there are over 40 countries and the legend displays only some of them.

```
counts <- table(dataset$country, dataset$year)

barplot(counts, main="My barplot",
        xlab="Years", col=colorRampPalette(brewer.pal(name="Dark2", n = 8))(12),
        legend = rownames(counts))
```

How can I make a legend that displays all of them and increase the quality of the chart because I am not able to zoom in so much since its a really big barchart.

Comment: Set `par(xpd = TRUE)` to allow plotting outside of the plotting region

Comment: @ChrisRuehlemann I am getting error: Error in width/2 : non-numeric argument to binary operator

Comment: Well, I'd suggest you follow good practice and post some reproducible data so that ppl can see what you have and try out solutions.

Comment: I think I uploaded what I already have, do you want me to post a solution as well?!

Comment: No you have not uploaded any **data**! What you have posted is code.

Comment: @dfgd please provide some example dataset, for example dput(counts) and paste the output, this way others can reproduce your error. It does not take time on your side, and   helps you get to your solution quicker

Comment: @dfgd you can use barplot(counts, beside = TRUE, col = terrain.colors(6), ylim = c(0, 250), legend = TRUE, args.legend = list(bty = “n”, x = “top”, ncol = 3))